# Owl slider move to first slide after slide show ends without animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel, owl-carousel

I am using Owl Slider
and i want to show the 1st slide after the last slide. Currently it moves back to the 1st slide after the slide show ends by showing all previous slides.
I need it to show the 1st slide after the slide show ends, like a LOOP
I have tried the following

```
$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
            autoPlay: 3000,
            singleItem: true,
            navigation: false,
            pagination: true,
            afterMove: moved



        });
        function moved() {
            var owl = $("#owl-demo").data('owlCarousel');
            console.log(owl.currentItem)
            console.log(owl.itemsAmount)
            //console.log()
            if (owl.currentItem+1  === owl.itemsAmount) {
                console.info(owl.currentItem);
                owl.jumpTo(0);
            }
        }
```

but it doesn't show last slide and `JumpsTo` 1st slide

Comment: you using owl carousel v2 ?